# How to get hyperlinks working in Mail for iOS 10 on iPhone 7

Tags: iphone, ios

Attached is a screenshot of an email. The blue highlighted text are hyperlinks that, when I click on them, should jump to a specific place further down the email. However, if I press on these links, nothing happens. How can I get these hyperlinks working?

[image]

Comment: Are you the recipient of the email, or the author of it? If you're the recipient, does the email include a link (usually at the bottom) for you to view the email in your browser? If you're the author, in what software are you writing the email script?

Comment: I'm the recipient. There's no link to view email in browser.

Comment: The email content was probably copied from a website. Functions that link to specific places in the page are only available on *websites*, not on emails. If you have the link to the website, you can possibly have these links working *on the website*.